# Why would this memory leak occur

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I get this error in valgrind

```
==399==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
 Direct leak of 240 byte(s) in 15 object(s) allocated from:
     #0 0x7f2a8cfadb50 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xdeb50)
     #1 0x401371 in push /src/main.c:88
     #2 0x401725 in buildTree /src/main.c:126
     #3 0x4027e1 in encode /src/main.c:31
     #4 0x402c8b in main /src/main.c:432
     #5 0x7f2a8c761b96 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
```

My push function:

```
void push(Heap* heap, Node* node) {
    if (heap->heapSize + 1 >= heap->capacity) {
        int capacity_ = heap->capacity * 2;
        qNode** arr_ = realloc(heap->arr,sizeof(qNode) *  capacity_);
        heap->arr = arr_;
        heap->capacity = capacity_;
    }
    heap->arr[heap->heapSize] = (qNode*) malloc(sizeof(qNode)); //line 88, where the leak occurs
    heap->arr[heap->heapSize]->data = node;
    heap->arr[heap->heapSize]->priority = node->count;
    heap->heapSize = heap->heapSize + 1;
    for (int i = (heap->heapSize/2)-1; i > -1; i--) {
        heapify(heap, i);
    }
}
```

I cannot understand why the leak occurs, because at the end of the program I clear the whole heap->arr

```
void freeHeap(Heap* heap) {
    for (int i = 0; i < heap->heapSize; i++) {
        freeTree(heap->arr[i]->data);
        free(heap->arr[i]);
    }
    free(heap->arr);
    free(heap);
}
```

[Entire code](https://pastebin.com/Rinu8wC6)

Comment: Try comment out `heapify` and rerun your program, just guess you have bugs in `heapify`.

Comment: For future projects, try do do things piece-wise with testing (like running Valgrind) between each piece. And each peace you add should be *very small* and easily testable on its own. And remember to build with extra warning enabled and treat them as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: For your current project, if you're using a VCS (Version Control System, like for example Git) then rollback until the error disappears. Then reapply each commit one by one until it appears, and you know what piece of code causes it. If you're not using a VCS, comment out code statement by statement (while making sure that you don't leave pointer access etc.) until it disappears. Uncomment until it returns and the last piece is probably the one that caused it.

Comment: My two cents: `qNode** arr_ = realloc(heap->arr,sizeof(qNode) *  capacity_);` should be `qNode** arr_ = realloc(heap->arr,sizeof(qNode *) *  capacity_);`, as `heap->arr` is an _array of qNode pointers_ and not an allocated space of _n qNode structures_. More importantly, you should always check the returned pointer from `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc`, they _can fail_. If you don't, you can induce a leak (failed `realloc` will **not** free the original pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run pop() as seen in your full program, the only pointer to the qNode previously pointed to by heap->arr[0] is passed back in the return value from pop().

```
qNode* pop(Heap* heap)
{
    qNode* result = heap->arr[0];
 
    heap->arr[0] = heap->arr[heap->heapSize - 1];
    heap->heapSize = heap->heapSize - 1;
 
    heapify(heap, 0);
    return result;
}
```

This means that the caller of pop() now holds the last pointer to that qNode and is obligated to make sure that the qNode is freed before the pointer goes out of scope.

Your code contains several places where the caller of pop() fails to do this.  Here is an example from buildTree (last line shown).  The qNode is leaked when buildTree returns because there is now no longer any pointer to that qNode.

```
Node* buildTree(Heap* heap, int* tab) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i) {
        if (tab[i]) {
            Node* node = createNode(tab[i], i, NULL, NULL);
            push(heap, node);.
    
    
        }
    }
     
    if (heap->heapSize == 1) {
        return pop(heap)->data;
```

Comment: i replaced `return pop(heap)->data;` with `qNode* qn = pop(heap);
    Node*   n = pop(heap)->data;
    free(qn);
    return n;` but still get leaked

Comment: soz, this time it was a heap-buffer-overflow in `qNode** arr_ = realloc(heap->arr,sizeof(qNode*) *  capacity_);` and `heap->arr[0] = heap->arr[heap->heapSize - 1];`. I understand that there are no more memory leaks :)

Comment: if it's not difficult for you, please tell me why heap-buffer-overflow occurs in my case

Comment: I take it that you already figured this out but the issue was that in your replacement code, "Node *n = pop(heap)->data;" should have been "Node *n = qn->data;"

Comment: yes it was a typo, but after fixing it the memory leak returned

Comment: That is because you need to fix all the calls to pop(), not just the one I mentioned.  As I pointed out, there are "several places where the caller of pop()" fails to free the qNode.

Comment: Just look for everywhere you see calls to pop(heap).

Comment: thank you very much, now there are no errors